# MySQL REGEXP match string with dash that matches string without a dash

Tags: mysql, regex, pattern-matching

Assuming I have a table `Table1` table in a MySQL database. The table has a single column called `string`. Here is an example:

```
**Table1**
mytext
my-text
some-text
no-text
notext
yes-dash
yesdash
no-dash
```

I want to get rows of `string`, from `Table1` that match a REGEXP that matches only alpha characters and a single dash (`-`).

I managed to get that with

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE string REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+[-]{1}[A-Za-z]+$'
```

From the above example dataset, I will get back

```
some-text
my-text
no-text
yes-dash
no-dash
```

Now, what I really want to get is any `string` from the result of the first query, that if the dash `-` is removed, that new string does **NOT** exist in `Table`.

From the example dataset, the following should be the output,

```
 some-text
 no-text
 no-dash
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the rows, you can use conventional SQL to find the rows that don't have a non-dash equivalent:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
  ON b.string = REPLACE(a.string, '-', '')
WHERE a.string REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+$'
AND b.string IS NULL
```

Also note the simplification of the regex, because `[-]` is identical to just plain `-`, and `{1}` is redundant (all terms have a implicit quantifier of one).

If you're not familiar with this idiom for finding non-matches, it works because left join always returns a row, but all columns are `NULL` when there's no matching row, and the where clause (which fires *after* the join is made) filter for only those rows. Also, you don't have to worry about duplicates as there's only 1 row returned when there's no matching join.

Answer (score 1):

This seems curious.  But here is one method:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 tt1
                  where tt1.string REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+[-]{1}[A-Za-z]+$' and
                        t1.string = replace(tt1.string, '-', '')
                 );
```

EDIT:

I think the above does the *inverse* (returning the unhyphenated version).  This is easily fixed:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.string REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+[-]{1}[A-Za-z]+$' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table1 tt1
                  where tt1.string = replace(t1.string, '-', '') and
                        tt1.string not like '%-%'
                 );
```